# Route host network traffic through guest Virtual Machine

Tags: vpn, split-tunnel

I have to use a VPN service for my work. It uses a custom VPN client and doesn't allow split tunneling. So, I can't access the local network or internet when I am connected to the VPN. So, as a solution I am going to use a Windows VM and install VPN client on it and route some host's (windows host) traffic through this VM. My problem is that when VM machine is connected to the VPN I can't access the VM from the host windows (neither by bridged network interface nor host-only interface).  Also, I don't know how to route the office traffic through VM

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not going to work. The VPN client (you say) is not split tunnel, so it forces all traffic through the tunnel and cuts off Host internet.

Putting the VPN in a virtual machine will not help because the VPN client in the VM will cut off virtual machine internet access as well. Host only is very restrictive so not helpful here.

You need a different VPN client that allows the use of Internet while the VPN tunnel is active.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I can't change the VPN client I have to use it and it doesn't allow split tunneling ( when I connect, it cut off the internet access ) by this assumption you mean it is not possible to somehow access the internet? any other workaround or solution or tricks ?

Comment: Without split tunnel, there are not any workarounds I know of. I have been using Virtual Machines and VPN for a very long time.